# Godaddy smtp settings in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp

Bought a professional individual email at Godaddy. Put their smtp info in the Larvel app, check it with all the possible values like changed the driver, port, encryption and more... Nothing seems working. Getting this error

```
local.ERROR: Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtpout.secureserver.net:465
```

SMTP Settings

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtpout.secureserver.net
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME="myproemail@mysite.com"
MAIL_PASSWORD="MyPassword"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="myproemail@mysite.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

And email sending code looks like this.

```
Mail::to("somebody@gmail.com")->send(new Message());
return view("welcome");
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply the below SMTP settings...
**Use PORT: 80**

```
<?php

try
{
    $email = new PHPMailer(TRUE);
    $email->isSMTP();
    $email->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $email->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
    $email->SMTPAutoTLS = FALSE;
    $email->SMTPSecure = "tls";
    $email->Host = "smtpout.secureserver.net";
    $email->Port = 80;
    $email->Username = "GoDaddy Professional Email Username";
    $email->Password = "GoDaddy Professional Email Password";

    $email->setFrom("address@from.com", "Name");
    $email->addAddress("address@to.com", "Name");
    $email->isHTML(TRUE);
    $email->Body = "My HTML Code";
    $email->Subject = "My Subject";
    $email->send();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // $email->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

If still, it does not work then...

This issue may be generated because of you are working with the local server. The local server does not provide a secure connection and GoDaddy's host needs it. so you can check directly on the live server.

Comment: No! I am working on it locally. It is live on Linode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).